# Tickets booking (stateful) web service on Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, stateful

I need some stateful web service ( let's say tickets booking in 5 steps 1) select ...5) pay ) and want to implement it using Spring (boot) framework

googling

> spring web service

tons of RESTful web services examples could be found... but according to REST manifest and many articles/answers (i.e. [Sticky Session for Rest API Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729535/sticky-session-for-rest-api-calls))

> REST client is made to call REST API and REST APIs should be stateless
>
> Statefulness harms scalability

It's very easy to create a RESTful web service in spring boot due to great embedded and autoconfigured libs, and I dont wanna refuse of it.

So I see some ways to overcome this:

1. Create RESTful web service in Spring Boot and add to there session and store state on it, and add sticky session load balancer to maintain scalability ( it's more difficult then stateless approach but doable). Yes it will not be **true** RESTful service, but it will work
2. Create **true** stateless RESTful service, keep state at

> temporary 'temp_transaction' database table which your code can consult to determine if a user is in the process of booking, say, a particular seat.

3. state maintained on client side not on server. So one of the way that i will suggest is that you can use cookies to store your state and temp data
4. Use some rich client side framework like angular or react ( im not good in it but believe there is the possibility to keep state presents in these frameworks) though I think anyway cookie used for these purpose so it's almost the same as 3)
5. Use Spring + SOAP. Soap can maintain state but I think this way is obsolete and modern newly created applications from scratch shouldn't use SOAP
6. Don't use spring framework for this project but use Front end framework ( mentioned at 4) + Node.js ( anyway it will be stateful)

So which approach better to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your REST service

1. could crash and will then be restarted
2. you want to scale and have multiple instances of your service

you should keep the state in a database or a distributed cache like Redis.

You will have to pass a session key or a booking reference in every request. For example in the header.